# Antd Design [Table] - How to expand specific row on table data load

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want to expand specific row of table in antd design. Assuming all the other things are working fine. In below code, need to expand row 2 i.e name = 'B' on data load.
Sample Json:

```
let tableSourceData = [{
   key : 1,
   name : "A"
},
{
   key : 2,
   name : "B"
}]
```

Sample Code:

```
<Table
   dataSource={data}
   expandable={{
      expandIcon: () => <div />
    }}
 />
```

Answer (score 1):

As I have searched for specific answer, but not able to find it. Now based of trial and error able to make progress.

Answer:

We can use prop: defaultExpandedRowKeys (https://ant.design/components/table#API)

Make sure it should be called after data loading and need to provide value as array of string/number

```
 { data? <Table
            dataSource={data},
            defaultExpandedRowKeys = {[2]}
            expandable={{
                expandIcon: () => <div />
            }}
         /> : 'Loading...' }
```